# Trouble debugging React Native in WebStorm due to Xcode error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, react-native, webstorm

At some point late last year Xcode updated it's self shortly after I started seeing this issue. I am using WebStorm to test my React Native code. However it still calls Xcode. It's really not clear what the issue is.

```
2021-02-23 13:08:36.058 xcodebuild[76340:2443891]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-17705/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371

Details:  (null) deviceType from bbc733777f1b9c21c951613dee303739076d8fd4 was NULL when -platform called.

Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f9d66d54900>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9d66d268d0>{number = 6, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
info Installing and launching your app on Test iPhone
success Installed the app on the device.
```

It never launches and I can't access the logs.

Comment: did you try filing a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com as suggested?

Comment: Did you find a solution?